# Breadcrumbs on product page don't reflect current url/slug when using multiple categories for product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, breadcrumbs

My Wordpress site uses Woocommerce for products to sell. But when you assign multiple product categories to a product and visit the product page (with `Product Permalinks` set to `Shop base with category`), something unexpected is happening. The breadcrumb link to the (parent) category is always the same one and does not reflect the navigated url. (This is the same problem as described [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/breadcrumbs-for-products-in-multiple-categories/).)

Problem in summary:

| Navigate to | Breadcrumb link | Expected breadcrumb link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `/shop/category-1/sample-product/` | category-2 | **category-1** |
| `/shop/category-2/sample-product/` | category-2 | category-2 |

I found no real answer on any source that fixes this. (I think it should be fixed, but some might say it's for SEO reasons, preventing duplicate site contents.) So to help anyone searching for the answer, here it is:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's going (wr)on(g)?

The breadcrumbs on the product page are produced by the [`woocommerce_breadcrumb()` function](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce_breadcrumb/). Which in turn gets it through `WC_Breadcrumb->generate()`.

Traversing further in the code, you end up inside the `add_crumbs_single()` function where the `woocommerce_breadcrumb_product_terms_args` filter is applied to the ordering of the product terms fetch. *(See [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) and [`WP_Term_Query::__construct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) for more info on this.)*

It's clear from the code, that they prioritize the term with the highest `parent` value, in other words, the term with the latest added parent in the database.

### Solution 1

Since this will always be the same for this product, you might want to add a filter to your theme's `function.php` (or using a custom plugin) that will overwrite this behavior. I got mine working using this:

```php
function prioritize_current_url_cat_in_breadcrumbs( $args ) {
    // Only if we're on a product page..
    if ( is_product() ) {

        // ..and there's a product category slug in the navigated url..
        $product_cat_slug = get_query_var( 'product_cat', '' );
        if ( ! empty($product_cat_slug) ) {

            // ..which we can find
            $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $product_cat_slug, 'product_cat', ARRAY_A );
            if ( ! empty($product_cat) ) {

                // Then only get that current product category to start the breadcrumb trail
                $args['term_taxonomy_id'] = $product_cat['term_taxonomy_id'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_product_terms_args', 'prioritize_current_url_cat_in_breadcrumbs' );
```

The rest of the `add_crumbs_single()` function will take care of traversing the category's parents etc up 'till Home.

### Solution 2

Alternatively, you could use the `woocommerce_breadcrumb_main_term` filter to change the 'main term' used for the breadcrumb trail. The filter function receives 2 arguments: the main term (as `WP_Term`) and an array of `WP_Term`s with all product categories found. And it returns one term, so you can search through the array and pick the right one you want to start the breadcrumbs with.

```php
function prioritize_current_url_cat( $first_term, $all_terms ) {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        $product_cat_slug = get_query_var( 'product_cat', '' );
        if ( ! empty($product_cat_slug) ) {
            // Get the WP_Term with the current slug
            $filtered_terms = array_values( array_filter($all_terms, function($v) use ($product_cat_slug) {
                return $v->slug === $product_cat_slug;
            }) );
            if ( ! empty($filtered_terms) ) {
                return $filtered_terms[0];
            }
        }
    }
    // Fallback to default
    return $first_term;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_main_term', 'prioritize_current_url_cat', 10, 2 );
```

Hope this helps anyone searching for hours and working through lines of source code..!

### Extra: Fix permalinks on archive pages as well

For tackling the same problem on the product archive pages, you can hook into the `post_type_link` filter and pre-emptively replace the `%product_cat%` part of the permalink with the correct slug like so:

```php
/**
 * Set product link slugs to match the page context,
 * for products with multiple associated categories.
 *
 * For example:
 *   when viewing Category A, use '/category-a/this-product/'
 *   when viewing Category B, use '/category-b/this-product/'
 */
function my_plugin_product_url_use_current_cat( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample ) {
    // Get current term slug (used in page url)
    $current_product_term_slug = get_query_var( 'product_cat', '' );
    if ( empty ( $current_product_term_slug ) ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        // Get current term object
        $current_product_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $current_product_term_slug, 'product_cat' );
        if ( FALSE === $current_product_term ) {
            return $post_link;
        }

        // Get all terms associated with product
        $all_product_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

        // Filter terms, taking only relevant terms for current term
        $matching_or_descendant_terms = array_filter( array_map( function( $term ) use ( $current_product_term ) {
            // Return term if it is the current term
            if ( $term->term_id === $current_product_term->term_id ) {
                return [ TRUE, $term ];
            }

            // Return term if one of its ancestors is the current term (highest hierarchy first)
            $parent_terms = array_reverse( get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) );
            foreach ( $parent_terms as $parent_term_id ) {
                if ( $parent_term_id === $current_product_term->term_id ) {
                    return [ FALSE, $term ];
                }
            }

            // Leave out all others
            return NULL;
        }, $all_product_terms ) );

        if ( count( $matching_or_descendant_terms ) > 0 ) {
            // Sort terms (directly associated first, descendants next)
            usort( $matching_or_descendant_terms, function( $a, $b ) {
                if ( $a[0] === $b[0] ) {
                    return 0;
                } else if ( TRUE === $a[0] ) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } );

            // Get entire slug (including ancestors)
            $slug = get_term_parents_list( $matching_or_descendant_terms[0][1]->term_id, 'product_cat', [
                'format' => 'slug',
                'separator' => '/',
                'link' => false,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ] );

            // Set url slug to closest child term of current term
            // or current term (if directly associated)
            $post_link = str_replace('%product_cat%/', $slug, $post_link);
        }
    } else if ( is_product() ) {
        $post_link = str_replace('%product_cat%', $current_product_term_slug, $post_link);
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_plugin_product_url_use_current_cat', 10, 4 );
```

***Explanation***

As @Markos mentioned, we tried to figure out the most logical and intuitive way to do this.

Basically, it checks if the current product category (slug from the url) is directly associated with the displayed product. If so, use that slug for the link to the product page. (Using one of the solutions above, the breadcrumbs reflect the url path for intuitive navigation.)

If the current viewed product category is not directly associated with the product, it looks for the first matching descendant (sub) category and uses that slug for the link to the product page.

This way, the user always sees how they came on the current product page and can easily navigate back to the category.

**Note:** If this snippet doesn't change anything, try an earlier hook priority and/or check whether the `$post_link` variable contains the `%product_cat%` template part.

Comment: Hello. The above solutions don't return what they should be returning. Any idea why is that? Where there any changed in the WP codebase?

Comment: I'm not sure, what does it return now in your case?

Comment: If you can share your implementation/code and the inputs/outputs you're getting, I could take a look.

Comment: Just tested on Wordpress v 5.9.2 with WooCommerce v 6.3.1: both solutions still work for getting the right permalinks on the product page and the extra solution for archive (product category) pages works as well.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand OPs problem. What I wanted to correct was, in case of multiple categories on a product, when we are in a product page we always get the right breadcrumb-path from the archive page we arrived from. I added both the snippets + the extra fix and the breadcrumb is always the same.

Comment: For example in the first snippet `$product_cat` is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243590/discussion-between-philip-and-markos-di-mitsas).

Comment: I updated the Extra snippet to fit used urls better to their context

Answer (score 1):

After a lengthy chat with Philip and troubleshooting scenarios when a shop has multiple layers of categories (thank you Philip) I found the following approach for the permalinks working for me.

```
function my_plugin_product_url_use_current_cat( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample ) {
    if ( is_product_category() || is_product() ) {

        $product_cat_slug = get_query_var( 'product_cat', '' );

        // get all the category of products
        $terms = get_the_terms ( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        
        foreach($terms as $term){
            $term_slug = $term->slug;

            // check if category page belongs to the category of the product
            if($term_slug == $product_cat_slug){
                $post_link = str_replace('%product_cat%', $term_slug, $post_link);
                return $post_link;
            }

            // or category page is a parent category of the product
            else{
                $all_parents = get_ancestors($term->term_id, 'product_cat');
                foreach($all_parents as $cat_id){
                    $cat_term = get_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat' );
                    if($cat_term->slug == $product_cat_slug){
                        $post_link = str_replace('%product_cat%', $term_slug, $post_link);
                        return $post_link;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_plugin_product_url_use_current_cat', 9, 4 );
```

Comment: Nice work! One very small issue is that if a category with an associated child term is found, it directly returns, skipping any terms after that that might be a direct associated term. (Hence the filtering and sorting in my updated code.)

Comment: Yes I am aware about that, but for some reason when I return the whole path (Cat-1/Subcat-2/Subsubcat-3), even though that's the correct version of the slug for the product, the breadcrumbs are again stuck to one version (instead of being dynamic). With my solution, returning only one subcategory (which is actually one of the categories of the product) the breadcrumb is dynamic. A weird bug that I can't really explain.

Comment: Is it the same with my updated Extra snippet?

Comment: Yes I used your snippet. It returns the full path of the product (which is the right way to approach it). But as I said that doesn't return the preferred outcome.  Which means either that `$product_cat` in solution 1 is empty or `$filtered_terms` in solution 2 is empty. The current way I have it working is with the solution 1 and my snippet above that returns only one child instead of the full path.